# Invalid initialization of dynamic array leads to read and write errors

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I'm trying to malloc an array of structs.

```c
typedef struct {
    long int val;
    long int time;
    long int last_used;
} pair;
```

so in my main I have

```c
pair **fifoVM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount);
pair **fifop1VM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount + 1);
pair **fifop2VM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount + 2);
pair **LRUVM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount);
```

and I initialize all of the pairs using

```c
void init(pair **frames, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        frames[i] = (pair *) malloc(sizeof(pair));
        frames[i]->val = -1;
        frames[i]->last_used = TIME_VAL;
        frames[i]->time = TIME_VAL++;
    }
}
```

But by the time I try to deallocate it, I get a corruption error from Valgrind.

I initially thought that the problem was using a `pair*` in the array but it still didn't work with just `pair`. I also thought it might be the `pair` going out of scope when `init()` returns but that also inst true because it would only deallocate the variable containing the pointer.

Also for some weird reason, LRUVM is the only array to crash, even though it's the last one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//since time.h only has millisecond resolution,
//I need to simulate time
int TIME_VAL = 0;

typedef struct {
    long int val;
    long int time;
    long int last_used;
} pair;

//Allocate the pairs for a given array
void init(pair **frames, int size) {
    //iterate through array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //allocate memory and assign
        frames[i] = (pair *) malloc(sizeof(pair));
        frames[i]->val = -1;
        frames[i]->last_used = TIME_VAL;
        frames[i]->time = TIME_VAL++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Command line arguments
    int framecount = atoi(argv[1]);
    int x = atoi(argv[2]);
    int NUM_ACCESSES = atoi(argv[3]);
    int NUM_ITERATIONS = atoi(argv[4]);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {

        //Allocate Arrays
        pair **fifoVM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount);
        pair **fifop1VM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount + 1);
        pair **fifop2VM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount + 2);
        pair **LRUVM = (pair **) malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount);

        //initialize all of the pairs in the arrays
        init(fifoVM, framecount);
        init(fifop1VM, framecount + 1);
        init(fifop2VM, framecount + 2);
        init(LRUVM, framecount);

        //deallocate arrays
        freeList(fifoVM, framecount);
        freeList(fifop1VM, framecount + 1);
        freeList(fifop2VM, framecount + 2);
        freeList(LRUVM, framecount);
    }
}

void freeList(pair **vm, int framecount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < framecount; i++) {
        free(vm[i]);
    }
    free(vm);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Beware of operator precedence in `sizeof(stuff) * n + 1`. Problems with deallocation depend on the things that happen between allocation and deallocation, so please show that. One common error is to modify the handles you got from `malloc` at al. (Or use a memory checker to see where data may get corrupted.)

Comment: Thanks. Your program requires command line arguments and does not protect against crashing if you don't provide any. Care to give us an examle use whare you observe the faulty behaviour?

Comment: @MOehm the only thing I do between allocation and deallocation is call init() so I think I must be allocating the pairs wrong.

Comment: @MOehm 10 20 50 1

Comment: Using all-caps for a variable `TIME_VAL` is conventional in C.  Normally, all-caps are reserved for macros and constants.

Comment: Put that information into the post, please. I have no problems after changing two things: Provide a prototype of `freeList` before it is used and change the allocations to `malloc(sizeof(pair *) * (framecount + 1))` or `(framecount + 2)` respectively. Note the parens around the sum.

Comment: You say Valgrind is reporting a problem — why don't you show exactly what it says?  You have compiled with debugging (usually `-g`) both for the object files and for the executable, haven't you?  Run it on the code in the question — not some other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the allocation sizes are not computed correctly: `malloc(sizeof(pair *) * framecount + 1)` should be:

```
malloc(sizeof(pair *) * (framecount + 1))
```

Note that your data structure seem to have an indirection for no good reason. Why not allocate arrays of structures instead of arrays of pointers to structures allocated individually?

Here is a simpified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//since time.h only has millisecond resolution,
//I need to simulate time
int TIME_VAL = 0;

typedef struct {
    long int val;
    long int time;
    long int last_used;
} pair;

//Allocate the pairs for a given array
void init(pair *frames, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        frames[i].val = -1;
        frames[i].last_used = TIME_VAL;
        frames[i].time = TIME_VAL++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //Command line arguments
    if (argc < 5) return 1;

    int framecount = atoi(argv[1]);
    int x = atoi(argv[2]);
    int num_accesses = atoi(argv[3]);
    int num_iterations = atoi(argv[4]);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iterations; i++) {
        //Allocate Arrays
        pair *fifoVM = calloc(sizeof(pair), framecount);
        pair *fifop1VM = calloc(sizeof(pair), framecount + 1);
        pair *fifop2VM = calloc(sizeof(pair), framecount + 2);
        pair *LRUVM = calloc(sizeof(pair), framecount);

        if (fifoVM && fifop1VM && fifop2VM && LRUVM) {
            //initialize all of the pairs in the arrays
            init(fifoVM, framecount);
            init(fifop1VM, framecount + 1);
            init(fifop2VM, framecount + 2);
            init(LRUVM, framecount);

            //...
        }
        //deallocate arrays
        free(fifoVM);
        free(fifop1VM);
        free(fifop2VM);
        free(LRUVM);
    }
}
```